# flashpunk desaturate world colors temporarily

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, effects

I'm developing an Android game with Flashpunk and Adobe AIR.
As a visual effect for slomo, I want to desaturate all the colors in the world temporarily.

(I achieved that using punk.fx, but on Mobile devices the framerate reduces dramatically if one uses punk.fx! - so I can't use punk.fx)

Comment: From what I see, there are a few classes in Flashpunk that have color transform, eg. Image, TiledImage, Spritemap. You could try cycling through the World's entities, see if they contain a graphic that has the color transform property, modify that and call on update on the graphic. But I'm not sure if it's going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flash.geom.ColorTransform` for that, with a transform set to `(0.5,0.5,0.5,1,64,64,64,0)`, should do. Apply this object to whatever clip you want desaturated. This will change brightness too, if you don't want to change brightness, use `ColorMatrixFilter` instead.

Comment: But I am using the Flashpunk game engine, so I only want to apply this to a world. And flashpunk doesn't work by adding sprites/movieclips - or does it?

Comment: I am unaware of that, check `if (World is DisplayObject) trace ('Applicable')` Anyway, you might be able to get this solution to work by attaching to `root`.